# Workflow for admin/user accounts creation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, database-design, devise, rubygems

I'm building an event registration system in Ruby on Rails. I'll need admin users as well as normal users. Is there any best practice for creating the admin users manually and not letting any random person "Sign Up" as an admin? Also, is there any way to prevent signups in general?

(I'm thinking about using the Devise gem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option #1

The simplest way I've found, for most scenarios, is to simply add an `admin` (boolean) attribute to the user model (I usually use Devise, but this applies to any `User` model):

```
# db migration
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

Then, thanks to ActiveRecord, you'll automagically have an `admin?` method on the `User` model:

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
  <%= # super-secret admin-only option %>
<% end %>
```

Then, your signup pages will be the same as they were, and new users will silently default to `admin = false`. Then, you can implement "promoting" `User`s to `admin = true` however you would like...such as in an `Admin::UsersController#edit` view in an admin area of your app.

### Option #2

If, however, you need the admin users to have their own views/routes/logic/etc, it might be worth separating them into their own `Admin` model (devise supports this as well). This would give you two separate models, each with their own routes, views, and controllers. One downside is that promoting a `User` to an `Admin` would mean actually moving the record from one table to the other. This option has a lot of overhead, but can end up being much cleaner if you need separate logic.

---

Which pattern you use will ultimately depend on your own scenario. If you need separate views/routes/logic for managing admin users, then choose #2. If you can get away with just checking for an `admin` attribute, then #1 is much simpler.

[Devise illustrates both patterns in more detail here.](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. So if I have a free-for-all signup form (no restrictions on who can sign up), how do I set users as admins? (For example, if I was using Heroku for production)

Comment: I edited my answer to briefly touch on this, but basically you can do that however/wherever you'd like. Usually, in this scenario, you often need to make an "admin" area of the site anyway, to cover multiple admin-only features, probably namespaced under `admin` routes. If that's true, then you'd just add an admin/users#edit form which includes an `admin` checkbox, and allows `admin` through as a param on the controller.

Comment: Also, if this answer worked for you, please accept and/or upvote it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for providing insight into this :) Could I also use the rails console (or the console for Heroku) to manually upgrade a user to admin or would you advise against that?

Comment: You can certainly promote someone via rails console, and I end up doing that quite often while developing. For production, however, since you likely want to start with atleast one admin user, it'd be better to include that in the `db/seeds.rb` file, or in a `myapp:setup` rake task, so that your admin features are usable "out of the box".

Comment: Ooh, that's really smart - completely forgot about seed. :)

Comment: Or another common pattern is include a "setup" UI that appears the first time someone runs the app deployment. It would be a form where you created the first admin `User`, as well as any other initial configuration your app might need.

Comment: Ooh gotcha. Do you have any good references for learning that?